# Why MediaExtractor is stuck on setDataSource?

Tags: java, android, streaming, exoplayer

I'm trying to play a AAC stream using the ExoPlayer. I'm experiencing the same problem I was having using the built it MediaPlayer: it takes 15 - 20 seconds to start on KitCat (probably the same happens on other versions but don't have any to test right now).

On ExoPlayer I was able to get some information about what's happening on background.

The flow get stucks on `MediaExtractor.getDataSource()` on `FrameworkSampleDataSource`, method `prepare`

```
extractor = new MediaExtractor();
extractor.setDataSource(context, uri, headers);
```

The log mention something about a timeout on `readAt` method

```
01-12 12:07:03.458    4537-4584/com.example.claudio.exopla I/NuCachedSource2﹕ mDisconnectAtHighwatermark = 0, cacheConfig is NULL(1)
01-12 12:07:03.463    4537-4584/com.example.claudio.exopla I/NuCachedSource2﹕ readAt: mIsMetadataRetriever == 0
01-12 12:07:03.463    4537-4615/com.example.claudio.exopla I/ChromiumHTTPDataSource﹕ readAt offset =0 , mCurrentOffset = 0 size = 65536
01-12 12:07:04.298    4537-4615/com.example.claudio.exopla D/HTTPBase﹕ [1] Network BandWidth = 0 Kbps
01-12 12:07:04.298    4537-4615/com.example.claudio.exopla D/NuCachedSource2﹕ Remaining (64K), HighWaterThreshold (20480)
01-12 12:07:04.298    4537-4584/com.example.claudio.exopla I/NuCachedSource2﹕ readAt: waiting end ( player case )
01-12 12:07:04.298    4537-4615/com.example.claudio.exopla I/ChromiumHTTPDataSource﹕ readAt offset =65536 , mCurrentOffset = 65536 size = 65536
01-12 12:07:04.298    4537-4584/com.example.claudio.exopla V/ChromiumHTTPDataSource﹕ mContentSize is undefined or network might be disconnected
01-12 12:07:04.298    4537-4584/com.example.claudio.exopla V/ChromiumHTTPDataSource﹕ mContentSize is undefined or network might be disconnected
01-12 12:07:04.323    4537-4584/com.example.claudio.exopla I/NuCachedSource2﹕ readAt: mIsMetadataRetriever == 0
01-12 12:07:06.328    4537-4584/com.example.claudio.exopla I/NuCachedSource2﹕ readAt: waiting end ( player case )
01-12 12:07:06.328    4537-4584/com.example.claudio.exopla E/NuCachedSource2﹕ readAt:Timeout ( player case )
01-12 12:07:06.328    4537-4584/com.example.claudio.exopla I/NuCachedSource2﹕ readAt: mIsMetadataRetriever == 0
01-12 12:07:08.328    4537-4584/com.example.claudio.exopla I/NuCachedSource2﹕ readAt: waiting end ( player case )
01-12 12:07:08.328    4537-4584/com.example.claudio.exopla E/NuCachedSource2﹕ readAt:Timeout ( player case )
01-12 12:07:08.328    4537-4584/com.example.claudio.exopla I/NuCachedSource2﹕ readAt: mIsMetadataRetriever == 0
01-12 12:07:10.328    4537-4584/com.example.claudio.exopla I/NuCachedSource2﹕ readAt: waiting end ( player case )
01-12 12:07:10.328    4537-4584/com.example.claudio.exopla E/NuCachedSource2﹕ readAt:Timeout ( player case )
01-12 12:07:10.328    4537-4584/com.example.claudio.exopla I/NuCachedSource2﹕ readAt: mIsMetadataRetriever == 0
01-12 12:07:12.328    4537-4584/com.example.claudio.exopla I/NuCachedSource2﹕ readAt: waiting end ( player case )
01-12 12:07:12.328    4537-4584/com.example.claudio.exopla E/NuCachedSource2﹕ readAt:Timeout ( player case )
01-12 12:07:12.328    4537-4584/com.example.claudio.exopla I/NuCachedSource2﹕ readAt: mIsMetadataRetriever == 0
01-12 12:07:14.328    4537-4584/com.example.claudio.exopla I/NuCachedSource2﹕ readAt: waiting end ( player case )
01-12 12:07:14.328    4537-4584/com.example.claudio.exopla E/NuCachedSource2﹕ readAt:Timeout ( player case )
01-12 12:07:14.328    4537-4584/com.example.claudio.exopla I/NuCachedSource2﹕ readAt: mIsMetadataRetriever == 0
01-12 12:07:16.328    4537-4584/com.example.claudio.exopla I/NuCachedSource2﹕ readAt: waiting end ( player case )
01-12 12:07:16.328    4537-4584/com.example.claudio.exopla E/NuCachedSource2﹕ readAt:Timeout ( player case )
01-12 12:07:16.328    4537-4584/com.example.claudio.exopla I/NuCachedSource2﹕ readAt: mIsMetadataRetriever == 0
01-12 12:07:18.328    4537-4584/com.example.claudio.exopla I/NuCachedSource2﹕ readAt: waiting end ( player case )
01-12 12:07:18.328    4537-4584/com.example.claudio.exopla E/NuCachedSource2﹕ readAt:Timeout ( player case )
01-12 12:07:18.328    4537-4584/com.example.claudio.exopla I/NuCachedSource2﹕ readAt: mIsMetadataRetriever == 0
01-12 12:07:18.413    4537-4615/com.example.claudio.exopla D/HTTPBase﹕ [2] Network BandWidth = 70 Kbps
01-12 12:07:18.413    4537-4615/com.example.claudio.exopla D/NuCachedSource2﹕ Remaining (127K), HighWaterThreshold (20480)
01-12 12:07:18.413    4537-4615/com.example.claudio.exopla D/NuCachedSource2﹕ readInternal - late!!!
01-12 12:07:18.418    4537-4584/com.example.claudio.exopla I/NuCachedSource2﹕ readAt: waiting end ( player case )
01-12 12:07:18.418    4537-4615/com.example.claudio.exopla I/ChromiumHTTPDataSource﹕ readAt offset =131072 , mCurrentOffset = 131072 size = 65536
01-12 12:07:18.423    4537-4584/com.example.claudio.exopla E/tmiMPEG2TSExtractor﹕ SnifftmiMPEG2TS @LINE=1372
```

I imagine this could be something related to buffering since MediaPlayer has similar problems. This only happens on real devices, emulator starts immediatly.

Comment: Just for sake of others reading this thread. This would happen when remote resource is not accessible. Underlying API NuCachedSource2 tries 10 times before giving error. So if you wait 5-10 secs you will get failure or error return code.

Answer (score -2):

1) After completion of use of **MediaExtractor** make null again.

```
MediaExtractor extractor = new MediaExtractor();
 extractor.setDataSource(...);
 int numTracks = extractor.getTrackCount();
 for (int i = 0; i < numTracks; ++i) {
   MediaFormat format = extractor.getTrackFormat(i);
   String mime = format.getString(MediaFormat.KEY_MIME);
   if (weAreInterestedInThisTrack) {
     extractor.selectTrack(i);
   }
 }
 ByteBuffer inputBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(...)
 while (extractor.readSampleData(inputBuffer, ...) >= 0) {
   int trackIndex = extractor.getSampleTrackIndex();
   long presentationTimeUs = extractor.getSampleTime();
   ...
   extractor.advance();
 }

 extractor.release();
 extractor = null;
```

2)

```
MediaExtractor extractor= new MediaExtractor();
File file = new File(this.fileName);

extractor.setDataSource(this.fileName);
int tracks = extractor.getTrackCount();

extractor.selectTrack(0); ..
```

Comment: Thanks for your asnwer. I'm afraid I don't get your code. I'm accessing a remote stream, not a local file. Could you explain how this is relevant for my scenario? Also, I'd prefer not to change ExoPlayer implementation (MediaExtractor is used inside ExoPlayer)

Comment: if you think , above information is helpful approve & upvote my answer

Comment: @NovusMobile r/Whoosh  :)
You just copy/pasted the Wiki doc; even including the three dots in setdatasource !